# Does CentOS fall into System V family? How is it considered to be while comparing with Unix System V family?

Tags: linux, kernel, centos, history, linux-kernel

CentOS is `"derived entirely from the Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL) distribution"` (more [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS)).

1. Does it fall into any UNIX System V family? Such as PDP-11 or etc?
2. If not, where does CentOS stands for comparing with System V family for zero downtime or performance etc?

Comment: PDP-11 is not an Unix version, but a line of computers produced in the 70's and 80's by DEC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CentOS is a Linux variant, and therefore shares no code with AT&T Unix System V.

The Linux kernel does support many System V system calls, and as such, a lot of software written for System V was able to be ported over fairly easily. These days, I'd wager that a lot more software is written first for Linux, and *then* **maybe** ported to a modern System V derivative like Solaris.

Linux also supports a lot of BSD system calls, by the way. As Unix and Unix-like operating systems go, Linux is the most ecumenical in terms of facilities it supports.

So, Linux is System V if you squint. It is also BSD, and it is also neither.

Linux is Linux.